# Using Linq to SQL to Check Table Privileges of Current User

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq

I have my database context set up and .dbml configured. When this was set up I made sure that the credentials where set to Windows Authentication. What I would like to do, is at the start of the application, hit each of the three tables in the single .dbml and return what privileges the user has on each. What are the options of doing this with Linq? The bellow code is how i was thinking about attacking it.**1)** can I query the result of `context.Mapping.GetTables()` ? **2)** what would the query look like to grab the privileges?

```
class privlidgeCheck
{


    public static IQueryable<IHS_XREF> getXref()
    {


        DAMDataContext context = new DAMDataContext();
        var tables = context.Mapping.GetTables();

        foreach (var table in tables)
        {
            var q = from x in table select x // query schema?
        }


    }

}
```

Comment: To confirm, are you using SQL Server's built-in table-security system, or is this an application-tier security system you've built yourself?

Comment: Note that Entity Framework does not expose SQL Server's permissions, so that's a no-go unless you want to use raw SQL. And if it's your own security system then we need to see your table definitions.

Comment: Its Using SQL Servers built in table-security system

Comment: What do you mean by "built in store"?

Comment: meant to say built in table security system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are logging into the database / server as the principal you are attempting to determine if they have permissions you can query using the function `fn_my_permissions`

```
SELECT * FROM fn_my_permissions('[schema].[TableName]', 'OBJECT');
```

However, specifying Windows Authentication could in fact mean you are connecting to the database using a single common account, the SERVICE account used to run the service in which your application is running (ASP.NET?).

In which case you will need to use some other means to perform security. Such as the ASP.NET Membership or ASP.NET Identity Provider models, or a roll your own security system.

I mention ASP.NET stuff because I am assuming that you are working on here, an ASP.NET web application.

Edit: Since this is a WPF application, you can use the above query statement to determine what permissions the user has on the table / view / sp in question.

```
using (var context = new DAMDataContext()) {
         var sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM fn_my_permissions(@objectName, 'OBJECT') where subentity_name = '' and permission_name = 'SELECT';";
         var param = new SqlParameter("objectName", "[schema].[TableName]");

         var results = context.Database.SqlQuery<int>(sql, param);
}
```

Or put and adjust that into your DbContext implementation (DAMDataContext), passing the object name as parameter. (This code block is just to demo)

As a final note = be sure to always dispose of anything implementing IDisposable (your DAMDataContext)

A using statement is a good way to do that.

Comment: Its actually a wpf application. There are a few reasons though not very good, in doing this over asp.net. I would like the application to detect the users credentials and check that against the SQL Server.

Comment: The user logged into the wpf app which is the windows integrated security account of that user.

Comment: I updated the answer to show how you can query the server to see if the user has permissions on an object. There's plenty of room there so you can massage it to fit your needs. In the interest of re-use, I'd make a method on the DbContext implementation (or some helper class) that allowed you to pass parameters through to the t-sql function.

Comment: Thanks for your help, this is definitely something I can go on. One quick clarification,  In the sql variable in the above code, would i need to change any of those values?

Comment: You would indeed change the query parameters / where clause depending on your needs of object name, type, and what permissions you are looking for. The above example just queries tables, for select permissions - this is only one single use case for an example. You should head over to msdn and review fn_my_permissions. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176097.aspx running the query without where clause on a database you have complete control - god mode on would help you alot to see what the results are on various tables/views/etc.

Comment: FWIW, you can use ASP.NET with Impersonation for SQL Server, but it's complicated (and using Integrated Authentication or Kerberos only works in LAN environments, not over the Internet). I believe it is possible to do it using SSO and/or normal forms authentication (where users still authenticate as AD users). But there's a lot of leg-work in getting this to work.